# Basis for 4th degree polynomials such that integral of $p(x)$ from $-1$ to $1$ equals $0$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Let $U= \{ p \in \mathscr P_4\mathbb{R} \ |  \int_{-1}^1 p(x)dx=0\}$.

a.) Find a basis for $U$.

b.) Find a subspace $W$ of $\mathscr{P_4}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $\mathscr{P_4}(\mathbb{R})= U \oplus W$.

I am having trouble thinking of a set of polynomials which fulfill these requirements.  Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Write $p(x) = a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2 + a_3x^3$. Then the equation

$$ \int_{-1}^1 p(x) \, dx = \int_{-1}^1 (a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + a_3 x^3)\, dx = \left[ a_0 x + a_1 \frac{x^2}{2} + a_2 \frac{x^3}{3} + a_3 \frac{x^4}{4} \right]_{x=-1}^{x=1} \\ = 2a_0 + \frac{2}{3} a_2 = 0$$

is a linear equation for $a_0, a_1, a_2, a_3$. Solve the equation and use the solutions to construct a basis for $U$ consisting of three vectors. Any polynomial that doesn't satisfy the equation above won't belong to $U$ and will span a one dimensional subspace $W$ complementing $U$.

Comment: If you have meant for $\mathcal{P}_4(\mathbb{R})$ to contain polynomials of degree less than **or equal** to four, then add another coefficient $a_4$ to $p(x)$ and repeat the calculation. Your basis for $U$ will then consist of four vectors.